Optimizing Nanogrinding Algorithms with Python for Metal Powders at Room Temperature
I'm working on an advanced nanogrinding technology that enables grinding metals like copper at room temperature, achieving results that are currently deemed impossible with conventional methods. The core of this technology involves a complex algorithm that manages the grinding process, prevents reaggregation, and optimizes the output. I'm seeking advice on how to further optimize this algorithm using Python.
Current Algorithm:
The current implementation uses a combination of:

NumPy for array manipulations
SciPy for numerical computations
Multi-threading for parallel processing

Here's a simplified version of the code:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def grinding_function(particle_size, alpha, beta):
    # Complex mathematical model for grinding
    result = np.exp(-alpha * particle_size) * np.sin(beta * particle_size)
    return result

def optimize_grinding(particle_sizes, initial_params):
    def objective_function(params):
        alpha, beta = params
        results = []
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
            futures = [executor.submit(grinding_function, size, alpha, beta) for size in particle_sizes]
            for future in futures:
                results.append(future.result())
        return -np.sum(results)  # Aim to maximize the result

    optimized_params = minimize(objective_function, initial_params, method='BFGS')
    return optimized_params

particle_sizes = np.linspace(0.1, 10, 1000)
initial_params = [0.1, 1.0]  # Change from dictionary to list

optimized_params = optimize_grinding(particle_sizes, initial_params)
print(optimized_params)

Challenges and Questions:

Performance: Despite multi-threading, the optimization process is still slow for large datasets (e.g., 1 million particles). Are there more efficient ways to parallelize or optimize this process in Python?
Memory Usage: The algorithm uses a significant amount of memory, especially with large particle size arrays. How can I reduce memory usage without compromising performance?
Algorithm Improvement: Are there more advanced optimization techniques or libraries in Python that could further enhance the efficiency and accuracy of this grinding algorithm?
Preventing Reaggregation: How can I integrate a mechanism within the algorithm to dynamically adjust parameters and prevent particle reaggregation during the grinding process?

I'm looking for insights or suggestions on how to tackle these challenges. Any advanced techniques, libraries, or strategies that could be recommended would be greatly appreciated!

The code does not run on my machine : TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict' (Scipy 1.7.1).

Note that you recreate threads for every call of the objective function which seems very inefficient, unless the computed array is huge. Besides, it seems you run 1 task per call to grinding_function which is also very inefficient (both memory inefficient and slow). You should split the array in N parts where N is the number of workers and then merge it again. I would be surprised if the parallel code is actually faster than the serial one.

Please note that simple-precision can make computation a bit faster though also less precise. It is generally enough for optimization functions since the results is generally sub-optimal anyway.

You’ll probably have much better luck trying to vectorize your objective function rather than parallelizing it right away; later, you can work on parallelizing it by parcelling out chunks to separate workers. You’ll also want to profile your code so you know where the CPU and memory hotspots actually are, and simple serial code will generally be easier to profile than parallelized code.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Code works after edits. And is quite fast on my machine, less than 1second.

Is grinding_function simplified? I would try vectorize that.
In current version its already vectorized:
results = grinding_function(particle_sizes, alpha, beta)
and this gives me 1000x speed-up for 10_000 particle sizes.
If you cannot post the exact code here, take a look at numba package. It allows you to write simple Python code, with for loops, etc. that later (just in time) compiled to much faster version, comparable with vectorization using numpy.
